# Rewrite URL for ANY subdomain with www to corresponding subdomain without www

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, apache2, subdomain

We have a multi-subdomain site that generates dynamic cotent depending on the subdomain text. However it does not work if www is appended to the subdomain. As some users are used to add www in front of every URL, we would like to fix it with a URL rewrite.

**EDIT**

I have got this far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.subdominio\.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.([^\.]+)\.subdominio\.dev [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1.subdominio.dev$1 [R=301,QSA,NC]
```

Surprisingly. It works well in one of my test subdomains, but not in the other:

www.otro-mas.subdominio.dev gets redirected to otro-mas.subdomino.dev (with and without an URI like /index.html). Just as expected.

However www.ono.subdominio.dev is going into an infinite redirect. Like this:

http://www.ono.subdominio.dev/ono.subdominio.dev//ono.subdominio.dev//ono...

Why is it not rewriting the host?

Comment: May be I dont have to scape the RewriteRule dots?

Comment: try RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1\.domain\.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Voted to migrate to webmasters.stackexchange.com.  Even if people here know the answer, the Q&A is likely to have more value over there where it is more on-topic.

Comment: Wouldn't mind moving it to webmasters. Don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Krister: yes using http:// did help, but still there is something wrong with my RegEx, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-zA-Z-_]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1\.domain\.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
```

You probably forgot the `QSA` and the `L` directives (search on the [Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for the explanation).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didnt see any effect on applying QSA and not sure if L makes sense here as this will go to a drupal installation that has its own redirects.

Comment: You should have precised this as well in your answer: it's Drupal :). And yes, "LAST" makes sense because when I use redirects like this, it's always a real redirect and I always want it to be straightly redirected, without doing any further things (= you may not want to process the URL as long as it begins with `www`, am I right?).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. You are probably right, I do not know much about redirects, and I am not sure if drupal relies a lot on them. About the www, I only want to process the subdomains that have an extra level of www.

Answer (score 0):

It does work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.subdominio\.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.([^\.]+)\.subdominio\.dev [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1.subdominio.dev$1 [R=301,QSA,NC]
```

I had some problem with the caches in my browser.

Comment: Damn. That's why I tell every day *all* my workmate to use Chrome in incognito mode: add those options : `--start-maximized --incognito` and you're **sure** that when you quit Chrome, everything is forgotten *including DNS*, which is not the case for Firefox which has its own DNS "cache" (even in private mode).